# Volume of intersection of sphere and cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, spheres, cylindrical-coordinates

Question: Find the volume of the intersection of the sphere x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2 and the cylinder x^2 + y^2 = 1.

So I get my triple intgral set up as (I am using cylindrical coordinates):

$$\iiint_ \mu(r)\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

where limits are:

0<= $\theta$ <=$\pi/2$ , -1<= r <=1 , $-\sqrt{2-r^2}$ <= z <=$\sqrt{2-r^2}$

I end up getting 0 as volume after calulating. Any idea's? I think i am setting up my integral wrong, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Using cylindrical coordinates and symmetry we get the following:

Go up the $z$-axis, hitting $z=0$ first and then exiting at $z=\sqrt{2-r^2}$. So, the projection is two circles, one with $r=1$ and the other $r = 0$. Our volume then becomes $$2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-r^2}} rdzdrd\theta $$ $$\Rightarrow 4\pi\int_{0}^{1} r\sqrt{2-r^2}dr$$ Using the substitution $u = 2-r^2$ and solving, we get the answer as $\frac{4\pi}{3}(2\sqrt{2}-1)$. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm confused as to where you got the limits of r to be sqrt(2) to 1?

Comment: @CalcGuy Very sorry for the mistake, I was thinking about something else. Very sorry.

Comment: No problem. Just wondering about z's limits now, why don't we go from     -sqrt(2-r^2) <= z <= sqrt(2-r^2) ?

Comment: The function is even, so that's why there is a 2 outside.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, cylindrical coordinates are a way of expressing any point by its distance from the $z$-axis, $r$, and its angle, $\theta$ measured counterclockwise from the $x$-axis. We can always restrict $r$ to being positive and $\theta$ to being between $0$ and $2\pi$, and still be able to designate any point with these coordinates. Try using limits where $r$ is non-negative because that is assumed when you use $r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$ at the end of your integral.

In this example, try using the limits
\begin{align*}
0\leq\theta <2\pi, \quad 0\leq r \leq 1, \quad \text{and} \quad -\sqrt{2-r^2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{2-r^2}
\end{align*}

The $r$ and $\theta$ limits represent a circle of radius 1, which is the projection of our solid into the $xy$ plane, and the $z$ limits contain the volume between the top and bottom of the sphere.